# Unity - How can I throw except out in coroutine "yield return"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

```
IEnumerator CoTest()
{
  yield return CoTest2();

  Debug.Log("Done");
}
```

If `CoTest2` had error , I want to stop exactly line I called ( `yield return CoTest2();` )
before `Debug.Log("Done");`

Is there any way to do this ? or better way

Comment: @shingo I don't think that is very helpful

Comment: _"or better way"_ - yes use `async/await` instead.  Cancellation and exception support is built-in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just surround your code with a "try/catch" block (see ["Exception Handling"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling) for further details). The further execution of your code will be immediately stopped when an exception occurs in `CoTest2` and you will fall through to the `catch` block.

```
IEnumerator CoTest()
{
    try
    {
        yield return CoTest2();

        Debug.Log("Done");
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        // Handle the exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not have any `yield return` statement within a `try - catch` block

Answer (score 2):

You can not have `yield return` within a `try-catch` block.

A little bit clunky but an alternative could be to use a state object like e.g.

```
public class CoroutineState
{
    public Exception exception;
}

IEnumerator CoTest2(CoroutineState state)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    try
    {
        var array = new int[0];
        var failure = array[0].ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        state.Exception = exception;
    }
}

IEnumerator CoTest()
{
    var state = new CoroutineState();

    yield return CoTest2(state);

    if(state.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogException(state.Exception);
        yield break;
    }

    Debug.Log("Done");
}
```

or depending on what exactly your routines actually do you might consider to not use Coroutine at all but rather `async Task` which allows you to

- actually bubble up and handle Exceptions
- directly result values e.g. a simple `bool` for indicating success or failure